Godot 3d и Tilemap
Делаю свою простенькую 3D игру на Godot и столкнулся с проблемой в tilemap чем дальше смотрит игрок тем больше какого-то засвета текстур в виде линий (пример на скрине) модельки делал в blender и не могу вот понять проблема в текстурах или нужно как-то ещё настроить tilemap или камеру игрока.


Приведите текстуру с мипмаппами. Возможно вокруг тайла отсутствует рамка и белые полосы - результат интерполяции с соседним (т.е. за пределами показываемого куска текстуры) пикселем.

Не очень понял при чём тут tilemap, но на скриншоте я вижу что-то напоминающее отсутствие анизотропной фильтрации

Ну вся локация построена в tilemap

Разобрался сам. Раньше я через фотошоп объединял 4 текстуры в одну, чтобы было удобнее работать. Сейчас же просто использовал каждую текстуру по отдельности.
